# Access Ant through a web service?

Tags: web-services, ant, xml-rpc

I would like to call ant tasks on a remote computer. Unfortunately, ssh is not an option. Are there other ways to do it? A web service would be ideal, but I am open to any suggestion. I know I could just code it myself without too much trouble, so I am just asking for existing solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the AntServer and RemoteAnt tasks in [ant-contrib server tasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/server_tasks.html)?